# Angular How to apply a directive directly onto Projected Content

Tags: angular

I'm creating a custom dropdown menu component based on [Angular Material Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

I have the following component

```html
<a [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" href="javascript:;">
    <ng-content select="[dropdown-toggle]"></ng-content>
</a>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [yPosition]="yPosition" [xPosition]="xPosition">
    <div>
        <ng-content select="[dropdown-header]"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <!-- ... --->
    </div>

    <div>
        <ng-content select="[dropdown-footer]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

I don't want to wrap the `dropdown-toggle` in an `a` tag (or any other element). I want the following directive `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"` be applied directly to the projected content

is there something like

```html
<ng-content select="[dropdown-toggle]" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></ng-content>
```

Or how can I use it outside the component like this

```html
<a [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" href="javascript:;">
    click me
</a>
<dropdown-menu #menu="matMenu" [data]="data"></dropdown-menu>
```